# Wanting to know about arc welding

Tags: meaning, differences, technical

to put into a proper context in asking,with the words;arc welding;could the origins of the word arc,still maintain as being the answer for arc when placed with welding,as of which is the identifying of an action?

Comment: I’m having difficulty understanding what it is you’re asking here.

Comment: Arc welding is welding utilizing an arc of electricity- an arc being a subsection of a circle which is roughly the shape of the ionized air (plasma) between the electrode and the workpiece.

Comment: so arc originates as from part of a circle and maintains with being added to another word,welding?(i wanted to clarify an idea i am trying to put together,(thanks for your input).

Comment: Arc originates as part of a circle, moves to the electric “spark” that jumps between oppositely charged objects separated by some nonconductive gas and that is what is maintained when added with the word welding.

Comment: thankyou,helps exactly,for what i need,most appreciated.

Comment: OED offers *"Electr.* The luminous **bridge** formed between two carbon poles, when they are separated by a small air space, and a powerful current of electricity is sent through them" (emphasis added)--and just preceding that, a borrowing from French, daggered as obsolete, "An arch." Perhaps what links the electrical application of the term with the geometric is this idea of a bridging a gap, and the classic form used in stone bridges.

Comment: dictionary, dictionary, dictionary

Comment: Your edit makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: well it was edited not by me, to me having to edit,so it is a collaboration of edit spin.

Comment: Discussions of *relativity* belong either in [physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com/) or in [genealogy](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Before it was edited the question was:  What does arc define as when stating, "arc welding"? -  To answer this specifically,  the  word Arc  when used in Arc Welding is defining a form or kind of welding. There are several welding processes such as Tig welding or Mig welding. So the word Arc is describing a particular form or kind of welding process.

Comment: cascabel-you seem to follow in such a way?

Comment: well,if you were trying to save instead trying to grave then it would of sounded better in commenting.

Comment: This is not a discussion forum. It is Q & A. Extended comments are put automatically in chat, and I really do not want to go there. Until such moment that you are able to express yourself better in English, I recommend that you post your questions at ELL.SE.

Comment: @Alaskaman didn't Joshua's answer explain that it is a kind of welding process? The Oxford online definition seems to state it clearly. the original question, as asked by the OP was the following `to put into a proper context in asking,with the words; arc welding; could the origins of the word arc still maintain as being the answer for arc when placed with welding as of which is the naming of an action?` I don't think you were referring to this version, were you?

Comment: @Mari-LouA  i  was stating what was only implied in josh's answer. He gave us a definition what an arc is and what arc welding is. He do not specifically  answer "What does arc DEFINE as when stating, “arc welding. My comment was an attempt to answer that  specific question. The rest of the question is nonsensical and edited many times and i have no idea what the op or the editors are talking about.

Comment: @Alaskaman are you suggesting that the editors were equally incomprehensible as the OP's edits? That's interesting to know! Anyway, thanks for clearing up *my* confusion about Josh's answer. I happen to think it's very clear, and did a valiant job under the circumstances.

Comment: well i would like to offer medals for those positive about my post.

Comment: I can't understand why people are voting to reopen this.  It's still unintelligible.

Comment: well,on most currency banknotes people would consider what is written on them,is,not only unintelligible,but supportive of the word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term arc is from the form of the electric devise used for welding:

***[Arc welding](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/arc_welding):***

> - A technique in which metals are welded using the heat generated ***by an electric arc.***

(ODO)

***[Electric arc](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_arc):***

> - An electric arc or arc discharge is an electrical breakdown of a gas that produces an ongoing electrical discharge.
> - An archaic term is voltaic arc, as used in the phrase "voltaic arc lamp".

[image]
(Wikipedia)

Comment: “devise used to welding” ??

Comment: josh-thankyou helps with putting into context,you have my informal vote.